# AdMob Mediation SDK not throwing failed ads?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, admob, iad

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

#import "GADBannerView.h"

@interface MasterTableViewController : UITableViewController <GADBannerViewDelegate >{

GADBannerView *bannerView_;

}

@end
```

.m

```
#import "MasterTableViewController.h"

@interface MasterTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation MasterTableViewController


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Ad failed");
    bannerView_.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)adViewDidRecieveAd:(GADBannerView *)view
{
    NSLog(@"Ad recieved");
    bannerView_.hidden = NO;
}

- (void) repeatAdRequest
{
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    [bannerView_ setDelegate:self];

    bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];

    bannerView_.adUnitID = @"ID_HERE";

    bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

    [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

}
```

The problem is, when I completely disable the network on my phone no ad shows up (obviously) but it also does not throw the `didFailToReceiveAdWithError`. Then, I go to re-enable my network on my phone and nothing happens. The ad doesn't get refreshed if it fails? I've looked on many other posts that claimed it could be fixed with `[bannerView_ setDelegate:self];`, that the app would throw when it received ads or not. But I can't seem to figure it out...does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to set the delegate on a nil object ... before you allocate it. The correct order of operations is

```
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
[bannerView_ setDelegate:self];
```